# Scrapy recursive scraping order with viewstates

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, viewstate

I am trying to use Scrapy to scrape the search results of a website built with ViewStates, recursively. So I start off with a set of keywords, trivially as few as two:

```
key1, key2
```

Then there is the possibility for each keyword to generate more keywords, as well as to return multiple pages of results which need to be parsed. This is done by conditional branches of the spider `parse` function, which yield `scrapy.FormRequest` objects with new keywords or "next page" instructions.

My issue is ordering. While scrapy claims it can be forced into a depth-first order with the option `'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1`, this does not seem to be the case with this recursive crawling. So far, I have seen consistently that any new requests generated in the parsing of the original keys occur after the entire original set of requests. So if `key1` is executed first and yields a new request for `key1.1`, the execution order is

```
key1
key2
key1.1
```

In my specific use case, this works for new keywords, but the site does not process "next page" requests unless they immediately follow the request for page 1. This makes scrapy functionally useless to me, unless I can figure out how to enforce a scraping order for these requests. Priority also does not seem to have any effect.

Can anyone give me guidance on this? Is this just beyond the design of Scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

The [`priority=` kwarg](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) is designed to influence the scheduler, to allow you to inform Scrapy of your requirement

By default, all `Request`s have the same priority, so Scrapy just picks one; however, since you need for the next-page to be actioned right away, you'd want to give it a `priority=1000`, which can be done through either [`response.follow(next_page_url, priority=1000)`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow) or, of course, through manually creating the next page `Request` and `yield` or `return`ing it